# how can i calculate bits perminute using Fast Fourier transform

Tags: python, fft

i am getting  signals as given bellow this data capture for just 10 second  (due to limited space here) now i want to write a code which shows bits per minute and i m considering the value 3.00 as a bit

What i did:

I just used a threshold value to print data to count bits per minute

as

```
threshold  = 2.8     # Threshold to do something if value is more than to that. 
if signal >= 2.8:
    print signal              
    counter  = counter +1 # to count how many times we get value more than 2.8 or (near by 3)
    bits_per_mint = counterx6 # captured for 10 second so converted it to minute 
print bits_per_mint   

data out put in 10 second  

1.7646050347
1.6970572917
1.6774392361
0
3.486762153
1.6310026042
1.6582465278
1.6384114583
1.6501171875
1.6769661458
3.9909898997
0
1.6688020833
1.6627473958
1.6689800347
1.6756423611
1.6579513889
0
1.6809592014
1.6504774306
3.7684857685
1.6463671875
1.67640625
0
1.6509635417
1.6736501736
3.5653423434
1.6581206597
1.6516666667
0
1.6449348958
1.6630338542
1.6605772569
1.6500824653
3.4554564564
0
1.6839409722
1.6495399306
1.6393663194
1.6684244792
------------
--------- so on
```

How can i do this  using Fast Fourier transform

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it helped you. You can use `time` module to introduce the delay in seconds in an outer `while` loop and then check for the condition if the signal is greater than the threshold if yes then print it and also append it to a list `bits_per_min`. Example code shown below.

```
import time
threshold  = 2.8     # Threshold to do something if value is more than to that. 
seconds = 0
counter = 0

while seconds != 60:
    bits_per_min = []    # this part of code runs for one min duration
    if signal >= threshold:   # to compare if signal is greater than the threshold value
        print signal
        bits_per_min.append(signal)
        counter += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    seconds += 1
print bits_per_min
```

Comment: this sounds good and may the refined version of my code but i want to implement FFT on this. So thanks for helping me but this not exactly what i am looking for. thanks

Comment: then what exactly you are looking for ? Explain in detail

Comment: I have seen some projects and they have developed a method that calculate Heart beat with image analysis using openCV and SimpleCV. Algorithm  detects the Redness of face due to the blood flow  or u can say due to heart beat. and then they have Calculate  the mean difference of the to subsequent images and calculate the Heart beat. To extract the most significant signal and to calculate the frequency they have  used Fast furrier Transform (FFT). That i dont know how did they implement. And hence i want to learn the implementation of FFt for this kinda problems